# Windows Azure Cloud Service connection with sql database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, cloud

I have been making requests to my cloud REST Service over the two past weeks. Everything was fine until yesterday.

Over the past days, I kept re-publishing my service to the cloud to test some of its operations with a client. I **DID NOT** change anything in my web.config, just some method bodies.

Yesterday, by making the simplest GET request to my service, through my browser or Advanced Rest Client, i started getting the following error:

The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service. The exception message is 'The underlying provider failed on Open.'. and so on

I suspect after doing my research that this means I clearly have a connection error with my database which I don't get since it was working fine so far.

I also tried to Stop and Start my service in the Azure Production Enviroment but without any luck. Also the server firewall is configured as it should be.

Any answers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience these generally tend to be azure service outages. There is currently 'Scheduled maintenance' occurring on all DB instances which may be affecting you.

[image]

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

Comment: obviously Azure could at least let us know about any possible scheduled maintenance at any time. I haven't thought about this at all. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: @andreas No problems, if you are interested in getting notified when stuff is down the best way is to follow the RSS feeds from the dashboard for the bits you use or link them up with ifttt to send you emails